# rails asset pipeline application.css loading itself messing up css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

until now, I've been loading my css files on my local environment without precompile like so:

```
= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap.min", :media => "all"
= stylesheet_link_tag    "bootstrap-responsive.min", :media => "all"
= stylesheet_link_tag    "font-awesome.min", :media => "all"
= stylesheet_link_tag    "ace.min", :media => "all"
= stylesheet_link_tag    "ace-responsive.min", :media => "all"
= stylesheet_link_tag    "ace-skins.min", :media => "all"
= stylesheet_link_tag    "datepicker", :media => "all"
```

but I want to change this to precompile now...so I did this in application.css:

```
/*
 *= require bootstrap.min
 *= require bootstrap-responsive.min
 *= require font-awesome.min
 *= require ace.min
 *= require ace-responsive.min
 *= require ace-skins.min
 *= require datepicker
 */
```

however, it loads the css files like so in the html:

```
<link href="/assets/bootstrap.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/bootstrap-responsive.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/font-awesome.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/ace.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/ace-responsive.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/ace-skins.min.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/datepicker.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

the last line loading application.css screws up the css and i'm not sure how to get rid of it. without it, it looks perfect. i'm not explicitly loading it..just using it to load up the assets. how do i stop that last line from loading? it appears automatically without calling it in application.css

Comment: What is the error that you are getting in your console?

Comment: realize the last bit of code wasn't showing up on there...sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I needed: *= require_self in the application.css for everything to work properly

Answer (score 0):

Often in your application.html.erb (app/views/layouts) will include with file.  Check there for the requirement.

Comment: no, it's definitely not. the first piece of code i listed in my question is what i loaded without precompile and it worked fine...only when i use the application.css does it add that line

Comment: is there a live version of this?

Comment: another idea is to remove any css or @imports from application.css

Comment: my full application.css file is listed in my question. I don't have any @imports and I have to include the other css files or it won't load any css